# How to add elements from string added from console to a list in java

Tags: java, string, list, while-loop, java.util.scanner

How I can add elements to a list from a input in java.

Like if i put:

Scanner reader = new Scanner("a,b,c,d,e);

I want to Have it like String[] a = {a,b,c,d,e];

Using any Scanner Methods with whiles  , Really i am little bit lost

Sorry for my English( is not my main language)

Comment: You want to use String.split(). See here for example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm After you read the string with the Scanner, just split it on comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add inputs to list like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class StackOverflow {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();

     Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
     String input = reader.nextLine();
     inputList.add(input);

     while (!input.equals("null")) {
         input = reader.nextLine();
         inputList.add(input);
     }
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know how many input items you are going to accept, declare an array before you start the input, then put each input into the array until you run out of array space.

The *better* way to do this is to use ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Using a Scanner, you can retrieve the next input (if you want an entire line, use reader.nextLine() to get that string. I'd suggest storing that in a local variable temporarily so you can examine it if you need to (you'll need some sort of termination sentinel or use hasNextLine() to see if there is more to read.

If you then need to return as an array, ArrayList has a toArray() method you can call.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, the default token used by Scanner is whitespace characters.

```
public String[] getStringArray(String input, int arraySize) {

     String[] stringArray = new String[arraySize];
     Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

     for (int i = 0; s.hasNext(); i++) {
         stringArray[i] = s.next();
     }

     s.close();

     return stringArray;
}
```